# Is IIS available in Windows 7 Professional?

Tags: windows-7, iis

Bit of a problem finding a detailed feature table that covers IIS. It's probably available in Windows 7 Professional. How many sites will it support, or is it unlimited as in Windows XP and Vista?

Comment: FYI, XP does not allow unlimited sites on IIS.  It only allows one.  This is one of the major frustrations of XP's IIS when you develop multiple sites.  IIS7 on Vista and 7.5 on XP support unlimited sites though.

Comment: On xp with IIS5 I vaguely remember having to do some command line operations to add/remove additional sites since the option wasn't in the manager UI.

Comment: XP allowed multiple sites, but had no GUI to create them.  It would also allow only one to run at a time.  IIS7x has moved to a simultaneous request limit - 10 for Pro (and Ent?), 3 for Premium,Home and Basic.  See here: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/479/iis-70-features-and-vista-editions/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIS **is** available on Windows 7 Professional and Ultimate (and maybe Enterprise too).

It will support unlimited sites and users.

Comment: confirmed by Brian Liang - Enterprise has it. Warp speed ahead!

Comment: Enterprise and Ultimate are the same (except for the licensing - Enterprise is VL only, Ultimate Retail/OEM).

Comment: AFAIK it's IIS version 7.5 not 7.0

Comment: Actually IIS7/7.5 on Vista/Win7 are limited, but not in number f sites: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/479/iis-70-features-and-vista-editions/ . Professional will only allow 10 simultaneous requests, Premium/Home/Basic only 3.

Comment: @Christopher_G_Lewis: that's REAL stingy of MS. +1 for the info.