# What is the IIS8/7 version that comes built in with windows 8/7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, iis

By version I mean is it IIS express ?
If Not which version is it ?

edit-----------------------

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/35859/is-iis-available-in-windows-7-professional) says "Yes" yet it in the end it say "MAYBE Enterprise too". Well my question is what is it ??

I have skimmed through the Wikipedia article mentioned below yet the answer doesn't tell me what version it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IIS which comes with Windows 7 and 8 (Pro) is NOT IIS Express but has a limitation of 10 Concurrent requests.

[Explained in detail here](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/iis-features-and-vista-editions)

Same with Windows 8:
[Windows 8 / IIS 8 Concurrent Requests Limit](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2012/11/13/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit.aspx)

> Starting with IIS 7 (Windows Vista), the behavior changed from previous versions.  In previous client versions of IIS, excess requests would throw a 403.9 error message (Access Forbidden: Too many users are connected.).  Instead, Windows Vista, 7 and 8 queue excessive requests so that they will be handled gracefully, although there is a maximum number of requests that will be processed simultaneously.

```
Windows 8 – IIS 8 Concurrent Requests Limit

Windows 8 (Basic edition) 3 
Windows 8 Professional, Enterprise 10 
Windows RT N/A since IIS does not run on Windows RT 

Windows 7 – IIS 7.5 Concurrent Requests Limit

Windows 7 Home Starter 1 
Windows 7 Basic 1 
Windows 7 Premium 3 
Windows 7 Ultimate, Professional, Enterprise 10 

Windows Vista – IIS 7 Concurrent Requests Limit

Windows Vista Home Basic (IIS process activation and HTTP processing only) 3 
Windows Vista Home Premium 3 
Windows Vista Ultimate, Professional, Enterprise 10
```

Comment: Do you have links to official documentation confirming the limits in Win8 as well?

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services#Versions)

> IIS 7.5 included in Windows 7 (but it must be turned on in the side
> panel of Programs and Features) and Windows Server 2008 R2. IIS 7.5
> improved WebDAV and FTP modules as well as command-line administration
> in PowerShell. It also introduced the Best Practices Analyzer tool and
> process isolation for application pools.
>
> IIS 8.0 is only available
> in Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8. IIS 8.0 includes Application
> Initialization, centralized SSL certificate support, and multicore
> scaling on NUMA hardware, among other new features.

You will need to download and install IIS Express manually on Win7 or Win8. Having said that,  you also need to install IIS via the `Turn Windows Features on or Off` within Control Panel->Programs and Features.